# Backbone.js grouping collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js collection with male and female models.

In my interface I want to separate them into their own individual columns. Is there a built in / recommended way to group in backbone.js collection?

Right now in my view / rendering code I'm doing

```
if male
  self.el.appendTo(#male)
if female
  self.el.appendTo(#female)
```

Is there any other way of doing it? Maybe using underscore's groupBy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter the collection by gender to get an array of the matching models

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend();
Persons = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    filterGender: function (g) {
        return this.filter(function(m) {
            return m.get("gender")==g;
        });
    }
});

l=new Persons();
l.add({gender:'female',id:1});
l.add({gender:'female',id:2});
l.add({gender:'male',id:3});

console.log(l.filterGender("female"));
```